# Can you access the View Hierarchy for apps installed on iOS device using UI Automator?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, appium, uiview-hierarchy

I know it is possible to use UIAutomator to access the view hierarchy of a given view/app that you have the appropriate keys/certificates for; however, is there a way to access the view hierarchy of applications that you do not have access to the Xcode project for? Such as those installed on a test device?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can run, hence have access to view hierarchy, only your app or any iOS system app e.g. Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

To access view hierarchy of third-party apps you can check [this](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-3rd-party-apps/) article, however you need to jailbreak your device and use [Reveal](http://revealapp.com). As far as I know there is no other way to do this.